# Installing Lucida Bright font for use with TeXLive (Windows 7)

Tags: fonts, texlive, windows

I've purchased Lucida bright from the TeX User Group (TUG) back in 2007.

The link provided in the email I received back then still works, it downloads `lucida-basic.zip`.

I also have installed a complete TeXLive 2012 distribution onto my Windows 7 PC, everything installed using all defaults (except a different location, on my `E:` drive instead of `C:` which is a modestly sized SSD).

I use TeXWorks for editing my LaTeX files and calling pdfLaTeX, BibTex, and MakeIndex. That's all I used.

The installation instructions that came with the font are very unclear about how to install on windows. What is clear though is that those instruction assume that I use MiKTeX, which I don't.

Has anyone had any success installing Lucida Bright onto their Windows TeXLive distribution? How did you do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: I voted for a duplicate, but if you are interested in installing in the Windows system, then the question is off-topic.